# resultset.next() always returning true when there is no rows returned by the sql statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

Query :

```
SELECT MAX(A.column2) FROM abcd A where A.column1= ? AND A.column3= 1
```

Code :

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
if (resultSet.next()) {
    return resultSet.getInt(1);
}
```

When I execute this sql query "**resultSet.next()**" is always giving result "true" even if there are no rows returned and resultSet.getInt(1) is giving "0" , if there are no rows returned.. My question is why resultSet.next() is always true ? ...I want to return -1 if there are no rows returned from the table How can I do that using resultset ?

Comment: Don't use an aggregation function like `MAX`. Also, [`resultSet.wasNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull--) is the only way to check if a primitive operation returned `null`.

Comment: The MySQL documentation states that `MAX` returns `NULL` if no matching row is found, so that might still count as a row in the `ResultSet`.

Comment: what about `String query = 
         "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(A.column2), -1) FROM abcd A where A.column1= ? AND A.column3= 1";`

Comment: After adding "COALESCE" I am able to return -1 from the query.. Thq sir

Answer (score 3):

From the Documentation:

> next()
>
> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position.

It will always move forward one row, even if there are no rows so make sure to check weather the value is **not** `null` or `""`

Comment: In my case, it is opposite even though I have ten rows in the result set. It is always returning false and not as true